# get integer value as input through autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am an AutoHotkey user; I need to get numeric value from an Edit control on a window to be used in some math calculations. However it seems the input value obtained from the Edit control (though contains only digits) is in string type; thus the script fails completing. You may show how to get an integer from an Edit control as input through AutoHotkey.

Comment: Please show some code, e.g. what you try to do with the number after grabbing it from the control. AHK is loosely typed, so you can use "1234" in the same places you can use 1234; so it should work as you say.

Comment: Maybe you need to trim some whitespaces. Otherwise, a simple mathematical operation like `myVar *= 1` will convert it.

Comment: thank for your answers. I shouldn't use percentage signs (%) for retrieving the variable in below expression:

result:=%ValueFromEditCtrl%+2

Comment: result:=ValueFromEditCtrl+2 is correct.

Comment: or isolate it with regex then do `var+0` and make the edit control accept numbers only with option `+Number` ;)

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Joe DF : I am trying to get your idea :) Can you give an example. MCL : thank you for reminding it.

Comment: `num:=RegexReplace(var,"\D")` :)

Comment: Joe DF, thanks ~ nice way.

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't use percentage signs (%) for retrieving the variable in below expression: result:=%ValueFromEditCtrl%+2
result:=ValueFromEditCtrl+2 is correct.